# How to correctly reference 'nested' tag with each={} in riotjs

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I'm trying to work in the concept of a loading tag I can wrap other elements to give a consistent loading display when retrieving data async.  Consider the following code:

> This example relies on `browserify` (require) but shouldn't make a difference to
>   the question

```
<test>
    <loading>
        <ul>
            1. = <li each={ items }>{ title }</li>
            or
            2. = <li each={ parent.items }>{ title }</li>
            or
            3. = <li each={ opt.data.items }>{ title }</li>
        </ul>
    </loading>

    <script>
        require('riot');
        require('./loading.tag');

        this.items = [
            { title: 'title 1'},
            { title: 'title 2'}
        ];

        this.on('mount', function () {
            riot.mount('loading', /* for 3 = */ {data: this.items});
        })
    </script>
</test>
```

As you can see, the tag is `<test />` and contains a nested tag `<loading />` which wraps the content `<test />` displays.  Problem is I'm unsure of the correct way to reference the items array (which would in the real world be pulled in via ajax).   I tried options 1 & 2 but nothing would display.  3 works (passing the data as opts) but doesn't feel right.

It may have something to do with `<yield />` which is how `<loading />` is displaying its contents but I don't know why.

```
<loading>
    <div><yield /></div>
</loading>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried your above code 2 got the correct result. I have a few issues with your above code that may be causing you issues.

<strike>1) I've never used require inside of a tag. I doubt it works when requiring a tag file. The .tag extension does nothing. It's the `type="riot/tag"` that signals a script tag is not javascript but a special script that can be used by riot.</strike>

<strike>2) You've closed the tag `</about>` instead of `</test>`. I think your riot tag just won't compile under these circumstances.</strike>

3) I don't know what version of riot you're using, but in 2.3.12 if you mount the test tag then any children (in this case your "loadings") will automatically mount provided you have already loaded the .tag file. I think the problem is that you're calling mount on your "loading" tag twice, which may divorce them from their parent.

I think your issue is that the `<loading>` tag means nothing when `<test>` is mounted. You then require loading.tag, which then allows loading to be mounted. Try requiring `<loading>` before you mount test. I made a js fiddle with how I would do it. Hopefully this answers your question.

https://jsfiddle.net/cm09mtc5/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  As for 1) i've got browserify working with the tag files and at the moment, it appears to be playing nicely. 2) That's a typo from me, sorry, i've tried to use a simple example outside of what I'm working on.  I feel you're on the right track with your last paragraph.  Being new to this library, I'm unfamiliar with it's internals to make an informed conclusion on why/how things work.  I'll revisit this again this evening and see if I can apply some changes based on your answer.

Comment: You were spot on.  I've moved the `require('./loading.tag')` into the parent tag (that would theoretically load `<test />` and everything works as expected.  Now I just need to find a way to be able to load a nested tag like this without having to declare them all in parent tags.

Comment: Yeah, 1 and 2 were pretty irrelevant. I'll cross them out of my answer. Glad I could help.